# How stormy (wave height) does Lake Baikal get?

Tags: hydrology, storms, lakes

I'm trying to find info on the storminess of [Lake Baikal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Baikal). I want to compare wave heights in a storm on this lake to wave heights in a storm on the ocean.

All I could find was very general information that Lake Baikal experiences a stormy season in autumn with approximately 18 stormy days per month. I could not find any hard statistical data on waves or winds.

Answer (score 2):

An article [here](http://askbaikal.com/2012/01/how-huge-are-baikal-waves/) says 4 meters. (No statistical data however, just a general information page)

> Waves on Lake Baikal may reach a height of 4 meters. Sometimes they
>   evaluated as 5 and even 6 meters, but it is most likely an estimation
>   “by eye”, which has a large error. Height of 4 meters obtained by
>   instrumental measurements on the high seas.

---

Another source, [The Lakes Handbook: Lake Restoration and Rehabilitation](https://books.google.com/books?id=bibY60NWOlEC&pg=PA179&dq=wave%20height%20lake%20baikal&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjf9ZqmqdHYAhVF-mMKHWaQD14Q6AEILzAB#v=onepage&q&f=false)
edited by Patrick O'Sullivan, C. S. Reynolds, (pg 179) agrees with this figure (emphasis mine):

> Baikal exhibits many features of an ocean: abyssal depth, internal
>   waves and seiches, tides, **violent storms in which wave-height
>   reaches up to 4m**, and deep water luminescence of uncertain nature.